# How to get a reference to the actor instance that runs a function?

Tags: scala

I have a program structured as follows:

```
abstract class OuterClass
{
    class InnerClass extends Actor
    {
        loop
        {
            react
            {
                case m: T => someFunction(m)
            }
        }

        def someFunction(m: T)
        {
            ...search function map for specific function...
            specificFunction()
        }

        ...extra methods here...
    }

    var functionmap=scala.sollection.mutable.Map.empty[String,()=>String]
    var actorpool: ArrayBuffer[Actor]=new ArrayBuffer(0)

    def main(args: Array[String])
    {
        ...create X actors and add them to the pool...
        populatefunctionmap
    }

    def populatefunctionmap() //defined elsewhere
}

class RunMe extends OuterClass
{
    def populatefunctionmap()
    {
        ...add some functions to the map...
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that I would like to make use of the extra functions available within the actor instance that runs my `functionmap` functions. When I've tried using `this` it refers to the extending `RunMe` class. Using `self` just results in a `not found: value self` compiler error.

Is what I want to do possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points I'd like to make about your code:

- `functionmap` is both a `var` and mutable Map. Typically you only need it to be one or the other; not both.

  - Same goes for `actorpool`.
- Access to shared, mutable state violates the design principles of the actor model.

Given the skeleton you provided, I'm assuming that you don't need to change the `functionmap` after it's been initialized. Instead of making it a mutable `var`, make it an immutable `val`.
You can do that by either an abstract `val` (shown here), or by a constructor parameter.

```
abstract class OuterClass {
  class InnerClass extends Actor {
    def act() {
      loop {
        react {
          case m: T => someFunction(m)
        }
      }
    }

    def someFunction(m: T) {
      // ...search functionmap for specific function...
      for (specificFunction <- functionmap.get(key)) {
        specificFunction()
      }
    }
  }

  // abstract val
  val functionmap: Map[String, () => String]
  val actorpool: ArrayBuffer[Actor]=new ArrayBuffer(0)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // ...create X actors and add them to the pool...
  }
}

class RunMe extends OuterClass {
  val functionmap = {
    // ...build the function map...
  }
}
```

If you need to change `functionmap` after the actors are created, then `InnerClass` needs to have a `var` which holds their own `functionmap`, which you change by sending messages to the actors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my [actual code](https://github.com/gazrogers/SWS/blob/master/server.scala), I do have both `actorpool` and `functionmap` as `val`s. I just made a mistake when I was simplifying the code down to what I thought was essential for expressing the problem. I think I haven't been clear enough in my question, sorry about that.

Comment: After reading your other comment, I think I get it. You can edit your question to improve clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your question has nothing to do with Actors. It boils down to:

```
abstract class Outer {
  class Inner {
    def innerf = 42
  }
}

class RunMe extends Outer {
  val inst = new Inner
  def ref = inst.innerf
}

scala> (new RunMe).ref
res0: Int = 42
scala> val r = new RunMe
scala> (new r.Inner).innerf
res1: Int = 42
```

The inner class's methods are only available on an instance of that inner class, so you need to start by making some instances.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I think my question may not be clear enough. There are a number of actor instances created in the `main` method. At a later point in time a message will be sent to one or many of these instances - at which point it will run a function from the `functionmap`. I'd like to be able to access that particular actor's methods from the function that gets run. Sorry for not being clear enough about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to access methods of `InnerClass` from the functions in `functionmap`, then it should be of type `InnerClass => String`, so you have the instance you want to call methods on.